# Regular expression to limit the character found to 2 or 3 not more

Tags: regex, limit, hit

I am looking for a regex that only takes out 2 or 3 characters. If there are more chars there should not be a match. See uploaded picture:

[image: Regex and result]

I already tried:

```
/^[A-Z]{2,3}$/
```

```
(\b[A-Z]{2,3})
```

Comment: Also add a word boundary to the end `\b[A-Z]{2,3}\b`

Comment: What was wrong with the regex in the picture? Why do you try to write something different?

Comment: TFB, that did the job. Thanks.

Comment: mkrieger1, the problem was that in the picture the ABBB the first 3 chars where detected. I needed that if the string was longer then 3 chars it wasn't detected.